# HTML5 canvas, fit to (rest of) screen

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've made a little web game, I'm using this code below to scale the game to the page size.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
// Attempt at auto-resize
function resize_canvas(){
    if (canvas.width  != window.innerWidth)
    {
        canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
    }
    if (canvas.height != window.innerHeight)
    {
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    }
}
window.addEventListener("resize", resize_canvas);
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", resize_canvas);
```

However, I'm now adding a menu in the top of the game using some CSS and I'm running into problems.
The game takes the size of the inner window, so anything displayed along with the game will cause the content not to fit into the browser.

How can I make the game "fill" the rest of the window?

(I've found questions on how to scale the game to the window, but I'd like the game to fill the window instead)

An image to demonstrate the problem below:

(Notice the scrollbars, which I'd like to eliminate)

[image]

Edit:
I'm quite new to web development, but I have the feeling CSS doesn't really work well on canvas.

Comment: try `html, body{ overflow:hidden; }` in your css

Comment: @Vashtamyty that kind of did it, but it still makes my game window bigger than it should, but just doesn't draw outside it?

Could I make one div (that scales to the page) and then put the menu & game into it, and make that div fit the screen?

Comment: Though I'm thinking CSS can't effectively change the canvas size (it only scales it, but doesn't change the amount of pixels displayed).

Comment: most probably the body and/or html have their default padding/margin. Try this: `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: in your html `<div><canvas></canvas></div>` and in css `div{ position: relative; overflow:hidden; } canvas{ width: 100%; margin: auto; display: block; }`

Comment: Hmm, the combination of `margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;` kindof does the trick.
The problem still is that javascript still thinks the canvas is bigger (but it's just not displayed).

I think ill try a combo of these comments with the answer of Quentin, that should give expectable results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you remove the nav height ?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var menu = document.getElementById('nav') 
resize_canvas();
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Attempt at auto-resize
function resize_canvas(){
    canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight - menu.offsetHeight;
}
window.addEventListener("resize", resize_canvas);
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", resize_canvas);
```

and

```
canvas {
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of that, but that sounds like a rather "hacky" solution.
If someone zooms in (which shouldn't be possible, but can't really block it). The menu will grow, but the variable will be hard coded, and the menu will overlap etc.

Comment: Ah, never mind, the variable isn't hardcoded, you get the element by id, so it should work while scaling. Only minor problem is that it wouldn't work "dynamically" when I put in other objects, but I'm not really thinking of doing that.

Comment: what do you mean by 'other objects' ?

Comment: If, for example, I would add an "ad" under the menu bar, I would have to add that into the calculation in the javascript.
Usually CSS could just "scale to fit" I believe, but it doesn't work well for canvas?

Comment: Ha ok. You can add a class like `interface__element` to all elements and sum height of elements which have this class instead of `menu.offsetHeight`

Comment: Or probably put the menu bar and ad in a div, and check the height of that div?
If you add anything to the "top div" it will automatically adjust the game below?

But I your given solution works great for my current project :)

Comment: yes, your solution will work too. But if you want to do a canvas game, try to not polluate space with menu, header, footer, ad